# Is Kylo Ren a new character for The Force Awakens?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, kylo-ren

The name Kylo Ren sounds vaguely familiar to me. Is he a new character created for the new movie? If so, is there a related character with the last name Ren already in the canon (movies, books, comics, video games, cross-stitchings, etc.) somewhere?

Comment: Are you perhaps thinking of [Ryu](http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/streetfighter/images/2/2f/Ryu.jpg/revision/20110724070854) and [Ken](http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/streetfighter/images/7/71/Ken.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20110709051921) from the *Street Fighter* game series? HADOKEN!

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - Maybe he typed up his answer on a tablet and was staring at his "*stylus pen*"

Comment: I was actually doing it on my mobile device while pondering what new features will Apple put in the next "*iPhone Gen*"

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[Kylo Ren](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Kylo_Ren) appears to be a wholly new character invented for the Star Wars 7 film. There are no mentions of him in any other literature pre-dating the revelation of his name in a [trading card](http://www.cinemablend.com/m/new/Star-Wars-7-Unleashes-Characters-Names-Via-Sweet-Trading-Cards-68622.html) in 2015.

You may be confusing him with any one of a dozen [Rens](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Special:Search?search=ren&fulltext=Search) found elsewhere in the Star Wars universe, notably [Kybo Ren](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Revenge_of_Kybo_Ren), a pirate from the 'Star Wars Droids: The Adventures' TV series.

[image]

Comment: That was it, Kybo Ren.  I watched that as a kid.

Comment: @xdhmoore - for what it's worth, I suspect the names are merely coincidental.

Comment: It so close!  It's just one penstroke off and it rhymes!