# Toilets in the Star Wars galaxy

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

For many years now, I've been curious about what bathrooms - and especially toilets - look like in the Galaxy Far, Far Away<sup>1</sup>.  I'm quite sure we never see one in the original trilogy, even in settings in which we can reasonably expect to find them - for example, Leia's detention cell aboard the Death Star:

[image]

I am also reasonably confident that there aren't any in the prequels either, although I have only seen the prequels two or three times (as compared to having seen the each installment of the original trilogy scores of times).  I haven't seen *The Force Awakens* yet, but I have asked around, and no one seems to recall seeing a bathroom there, either.

If we assume that the anatomical differences between the various sentient species aren't merely cosmetic and skin-deep, then the sheer logistics of providing facilities for all the different species that inhabit the Star Wars universe - or even just the most common and widespread species, like humans, Twi'leks, Rodians, Bothans, Transdoshans, and Wookiees - would be staggering.

Of course, there is no need to have facilities designed to accommodate a species that will probably never use them.  Therefore, the typical Wookiee home on Kashyyk would probably have facilities designed specifically for Wookiees (because they wouldn't anticipate a Hutt needing to use their bathroom), and Owen and Beru Lars presumably had a bathroom not that different from our own (because they didn't expect an Aqualish to use their toilet).  And in some cases, a sentient species might not have toilets of any kind - I would assume that Ewoks do their business in crude pit latrines, or even just out in the woods somewhere.

But there are plenty of places in the galaxy where many species came together, like the Mos Eisley Cantina, or the Jedi Temple, or the Galactic Senate building.  In these cases, the public bathrooms would have to accommodate all manner of different species, and the anatomical differences between the species would necessitate drastically different types of toilets.

#### Have we ever seen a bathroom/toilet in the Star Wars universe, or seen a description of one?  And how did plumbers in the Galaxy Far, Far Away accommodate for a reasonable number of the most common species in the finite space available to them?

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>*Full Disclosure:  This curiosity was born out of a question my friend once asked me*:</sub>

> <sub>"If you had the choice of being best friends with Chewbacca, and hanging out with him all the time, so your relationship was just like the Chewbacca/Han Solo partnership, or being best friends with R2-D2, and hanging out with him all the time, just like the Luke/R2-D2 partnership (minus C-3PO), and assuming you could perfectly understand everything that was said by whichever best friend you chose, who would you pick?"</sub>

<sub>*I gave the question more thought than I would like to admit, and eventually, I started pondering the logistics of sharing my apartment with a Wookiee.  I figured my food expenses would drastically increase, but that didn't bother me as much as the next problem that occurred to me: Could I handle sharing a bathroom with Chewbacca?  That is to say, can a toilet designed for use by humans handle the kind of punishment a Wookiee is likely to dish out?  How long does it take for a bathroom to become habitable again after a Wookiee uses it?  Would I have to leave the apartment for a few hours so it could air out after Chewbacca does his business?  The other problems that would likely arise from having a Wookiee roommate - shedding; fleas; having to clean enormous hairballs out of the shower drain every morning; angry neighbors complaining and calling the cops because Chewie keeps eating their pets; etc - would probably pale in comparison to the horror of modern plumbing's inability to cope with the digestive processes of a seven foot tall carnivorous space-ape with a penchant for eating raw Endor-monkey meat.*</sub>

<sub>*Peter Mayhew, AKA Chewbacca, has commented on this issue [on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/3ynh83/what_is_a_really_inappropriate_question_you_have/), but he would only say this:*</sub>

> Let's just say, even toilets let Wookiees win.
> Cheers,
> Peter Mayhew

Comment: I can give you a Legends answer. Is that ok? I'm not sure a canon answer exists.

Comment: @RogueJedi - I will accept any level of canonicity, but of course, the higher the canonicity, the better.

Comment: @WadCheber Please use the Star Wars Legends tag to indicate that Legends sources are acceptable.

Comment: So when one visits a friend of a different species, one should bring it's own toilet ? For example Jabba visiting a human!

Comment: @RickSanchez - No, but if a Hutt visits a poor moisture farmer who has presumably never had a Hutt living with him, the visiting Hutt shouldn't expect to find a Hutt toilet.

Comment: @WadCheber Yeah I get it, just thought that it'd be a funny thing it point out. Meant it as a joke.

Comment: @RickSanchez - Anti-Hutt discrimination is not a laughing matter.  GOOD DAY, SIR.

Comment: @RickSanchez - Also, I have a feeling that giant space slug crimelords just poop wherever they happen to be at the time the need arises.

Comment: This problem was addressed in a Golden Age story: "[The Empire State Building had a]  huge golden sign 'Public Washport' riding on its spire. Attendants directed traffic from a large circular desk in the lobby. 'Mercurians, seventy-eighth floor. A group Vegans, fourteenth floor right. B group, fourteenth floor left. C group, fifteenth floor right. D group, fifteenth floor left. Sirians, forty-ninth floor. Female humans fiftieth floor right, males, fiftieth floor left. Uranians, basement . . .'"

Comment: If it's in canon, it might be in the Luke Learning Basic Maths book

Comment: Didn't you know? http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NobodyPoops

Comment: One word: dingleberries.

Comment: Ah looks like it's time for a *hands Hobbie the CSI glasses* Refresher Course http://cow.org/csi/

Comment: Ahem!   Related??!  **[Kybo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outhouse#Kybo)** and **[Kybo Ren](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/102246/kylo-ren-vs-kybo-ren)**  !!

Comment: Updated my answer with a canon source.

Comment: You know those kits of adapters you but to handle charging all the devices? It's like that.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

### Update:

In *Star Wars: The Clone Wars*, we see a sign labeled "LATRINE" in a bar, with symbols representing various races. From that, we can assume that bathrooms provided options for at least a few different physiques.

[image]

### Old Answer:

In the Legends continuity, it seems human [toilets](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Toilet) were essentially the same as our own.

[image: Star Wars toilet 1]

[image: Star Wars toilet 2]

I can find no reference to the toilets of other species or instances of other species using human toilets. However, given that [many species could breed with humans](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Human/Legends#Physiology), I would assume that many species had similar enough bodies to use human toilets just fine.

I did find this non-canon Star Wars-themed MAD comic, though:

[image: MAD Star Wars comic]

Comment: I actually used to own that issue of MAD, and I had completely forgotten about it until you posted the picture!  :)

Comment: In KotoR II, you do see places with sinks throughout the Peragus facility, especially in the dorm areas, though they are simply called refreshers.

Comment: That Mad comic is instant headcanon!

Comment: I like how the wookieepedia lists appearances of toilets. Someone had way too much time on their hands.

Comment: And here I was expecting [that clip of Gary the Stormtrooper from Robot Chicken where he sets the bathroom on fire](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-3Kor78QPNw). Or the one where [he pilots the death star whilst the regular pilot goes to the toilet](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=02IBDoIOpJE).

Comment: I never thought that the question could have answer...

Comment: 1.  I forgot I hadn't accepted an answer.  
2.  I am having trouble deciding which answer is best.  
3.  One will be accepted.  The other one -  or both - will get a bounty.  I'll figure out which tomorrow.  Don't take it personally if I accept the other one.  I like both, and you'll both get something.

Comment: @WadCheber I understand. I like my answer more, but I upvoted the other one.

Comment: And your answer will get more than just the 15 points you'd get from acceptance.  MUCH more.

Comment: Upvote for posting the MAD comic, it's the first thing I thought of when reading the question. Canon enough for this fan!

Comment: I opened a bounty for you on another question.  If I opened it here, I'd have to give you 500 points.  Instead, I found another great answer from you on a different question and you'll get 200 points there.  :)

Comment: @WadCheber Thanks.

Answer (score 32):

The *Legends* novel [*Yoda: Dark Rendezvous*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Yoda:_Dark_Rendezvous), by Sean Stewart, has a nice description of one of the stalls in a "men's refresher" in a spaceport on Coruscant:

> *"It was one of the big multipurpose stalls, with a toilet, urinal, trough, collection rods, and a telescoping drain with suction action."*

Once the protagonists are on board the ship, one of the humans has to ask a crew member for directions to a refresher station:

> *"Embarrassing as that had been been, coming out two minutes later to confess that she couldn't figure out which bits of plumbing to use had been worse."*

I think Mr. Stewart must have been inspired by that MAD comic...

Comment: I had the same problem in the airport at Copenhagen.

Answer (score 21):

## *The Mandalorian*

["Chapter 1"](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Mandalorian_Chapter_1) ([*The Mandalorian*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Mandalorian) 1x01; 2019) shows a "vac tube" <sup>(1)</sup> — a stainless steel toilet — in an alcove inside the titular character's ship:

[image: A vac tube on The Mandalorian's ship]

The phrase "vac tube" seems to be derived from "evacuation" (i.e., of bodily waste), as heard in the episode's dialogue:

> *"I think I have to use the vac tube ... if you've never seen a fledgling Mythrol evacuate their thorax, you're a lucky guy, trust me."*
>
> — A [Mythrol](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Mythrol) prisoner, lying to his [Mandalorian](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Mandalorian) captor for a chance to search the Mandalorian's ship.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> [The Mandalorian answers a huge Star Wars question: How do they use the toilet?](https://www.syfy.com/syfywire/the-mandalorian-star-wars-toilets-use-the-bathroom)

## *Star Wars Rebels*

In ["Double Agent Droid"](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Double_Agent_Droid) ([*Star Wars Rebels*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Rebels) 3x19; 2017), AP-5 attempts to have a serious conversation with Wedge Antilles in the refresher aboard a *Sentinel*-class shuttle.  Wedge's posture and his frustrated reaction indicate that he is in the middle of *using* the facilities when AP-5 interrupts:

[image: AP-5 wants to discuss a security concern during Wedge's bathroom break.]

Although the plumbing fixture itself is not shown, its method of use resembles that of a western-style toilet or urinal.

Comment: +1! The *sink* certainly looks like a normal earth sink - I wonder what the toilet/urinal looks like?

Comment: You deserve many, many bonus points for watching the first episode of the first Star Wars show on the first day of Disney’s brand new, high-profile streaming service and thinking hey, I need to update my answer to that toilet question on the internet from two and a half years ago.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite — Never let it be said that I haven't got my priorities straight.

Answer (score 4):

As seen in this close up from the schematics of the *Millennium Falcon* (from the canon [YT-1300 Millennium Falcon Owners' Workshop Manual](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/YT-1300_Millennium_Falcon_Owners%27_Workshop_Manual)), Item #46 (the refresher), is a full refresher aka the Star Wars term for a bathroom.

It has a sonic shower (shower stall), a sanitation station (sink), and a privy (toilet).

[image: This image depicts a schematic of the Millennium Falcon showing a top-down view of the refresher]

I do find it a bit scary that the Falcon which is meant to transport 2-8 beings only has a single refresher.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of adding in the source and tidying your answer up a little.