# Does Chewbacca shed?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, chewbacca

I have NEVER heard a mention of his long hair making Han mad when he goes to....shower?....so here goes with my question, which may or may not have a canon answer (Yes Legends canon, that means you!) but I'll take just about any justification for the answer.

**Does Chewbacca shed**?

Comment: Are YOU going to tell him off if he does?  I'm not!  I like my arms just where they are :)

Comment: I won't.....but maybe we can get C-3PO to?

Comment: I know Zaalbar (the Wookiee from KOTOR) gets very angry when his buddy Mission tells him to bathe.  If he's a fair representative of the Wookiee mentality, maybe Wookiees *don't* shower.

Comment: [Somewhat related](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/112835/toilets-in-the-galaxy-far-far-away) (at least inasmuch as the note mentions wookiee shedding specifically).

Comment: At his size he probably garages.

Comment: No idea, but [Will.i.am probably does](https://img.buzzfeed.com/buzzfeed-static/static/enhanced/webdr05/2013/4/23/8/enhanced-buzz-30756-1366721816-2.jpg).

Comment: Does he go to shower?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

### Yes he does.

> Fingers straining, she [Rey] just managed to reach the shield controls and flick them to life, **in the process having to brush away several clumps of excessively long, rough yellow-brown hairs that had become caught in the console.** Relieved, she straightened in the pilot’s seat and resumed full command, stabilizing the vessel
>
> <sub><sup>[The Force Awakens - Official novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens_(novel))</sup></sub>

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I was looking for, perfect answer with a canon (and Disney Canon at that!) explanation! +1

Comment: @Anoplexian - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1wrSsIVqHpM

Answer (score 18):

**Yes**.

From Issue #1 of the Disney canon comic *[Star Wars: Chewbacca](http://marvel.com/comics/series/19709/chewbacca_2015_-_present)*:

[image: Chewbacca shedding]

Comment: Also an excellent (and fully canon) source.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of putting up a less crappy picture :-)

Comment: @Richard Thanks. I took the image when I was leafing through a comic at Disney World. I would've brought it home and scanned it but the price was too marked up.

Comment: It's important to support the studio who produce them though. Downloading them via piratebay (for free) is just plain wrong.

Comment: @Richard Is that directed at me, or just general advice?

Comment: It's just good general advice :-)